# What is the usage of -e flag in sed?

Tags: bash, sed, flags

From some online reading, it seems that sed's `-e` flag usage is to note a sed script

e.g:

`sed -i -e 's/default_language/language/g' "$CONF_FILE"`

but from self-testing and some online search, it seems that this line should also work:

`sed -i 's/default_language/language/g' "$CONF_FILE"`

So what do I need `-e` for? Is it only useful for cases I'd like to write several scripts in a row? That can also be managed with `;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html):

> If no `-e`, `--expression`, `-f`, or `--file` option is given, then **the first non-option argument is taken as the  sed
> script  to interpret**.  All remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are specified, then
> the standard input is read.

As you already mentioned, `-e` may be used for multiple commands.

```
sed 'cmd1; cmd2'
sed -e 'cmd1; cmd2'
sed -e 'cmd1' -e 'cmd2'
```

Comment: N.B. Some sed commands must end in a newline e.g. `r`,`R`,`w`,`W`,`i`,`c`,`a` and `e`,in these cases `-e` before the string which ends in them allows further such strings to be entered on the same line (one liners). Grouped commands using using the above commands `{` and `}` can also be entered on one line e.g. `sed -e '/pattern/{r insertFile' -e 'd}' file`. Also note that a single string needs no `-e` option whereas 2 or more must have the option for each such string.

Comment: right. BSD sed requires even more `-e`, because, for example, `sed 'ba;:a'` would not work with BSD sed. and for newlines sometimes i use Bash's `$'...\n...'`.

Comment: Quoting strings using `$'...'` is useful but opens another box of snakes as does the use of double quotes for allowing shell interpolation. I generally go with single quotes and use the long winded `'\''` idiom to include a single quote. However each to his own.

Comment: right. can use only the `$'\n' ` part,  like this: `sed 'cmd; ...'$'\n''cmd; ...' `

Comment: so basically the added value of -e is that i can give other non-option arguments before the sed script, and then give the sed script with -e?

Comment: for me `-e` being optional is the *value*. :)

Comment: "give other non-option arguments before the sed script, ..." -- you mean something like `sed file -e 'cmd...'`? personally i would avoid this style which is usually only supported by GNU utils.

Comment: @pynexj yes something like that, i probably wouldn't use it but seems like it's not giving any other added value since you can omit the flag and still run the command with basically the same input